# How would I use GLSL to generate a texture with all of the eye-space normals of every fragment in the frame, in RGB data (a la normal mapping)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, normals

I need to somehow render a texture, like a screenshot of the scene, except instead of the colour data of the point behind each fragment, the normal is stored. It would generate a texture that looks somewhat like a normal map (such as [this](http://www.ericspitler.com/images/2d/normalmap.jpg)). I've done quite a bit of research (to little avail) but my instincts tell me that the easiest method for this would be a GLSL shader.

So would there be any possible way to implement this, GLSL or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering the normal vectors to a separate render target is common technique for [deferred lighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading). You can found a good introduction [here](http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/19/) (it's using DirectX and HLSL, but the concepts are quite clear and can be easily ported to OpenGL/GLSL).

Answer (score 0):

The actual GLSL shader that write out normal information is very simple (much simpler than dealing with light information)

I have created a 'normal shader' in GLSL using KickJS Shader Editor:

http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html#ahFzfmtpY2tzdGFydGVuZ2luZXJjCxIWb3JnLmtpY2tqcy5zaGFyZWQuVXNlciIbbW9ydGVuQG5vYmVsLWpvZXJnZW5zZW4uY29tDAsSGG9yZy5raWNranMuc2hhcmVkLlNoYWRlciIORGVmYXVsdCBzaGFkZXIM

It should be simple to port to whatever version of GLSL you want to use.